# Rails: Pass parameters for child record when creating parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is seriously `rails` newbie. I know I can use `before_save` and `after_save` hooks in my model to control writing the has_many record when I create the parent, but I don't know how to pass the values I want to be created in that child record.

In my scenario, a user `has_many memberships` to schools. At the moment, when I create a User, it creates a blank `membership` record which doesn't have the correct initial values. How do I pass the User the values it needs to insert into the has_many record at init?

What I have been doing is manually creating the membership record after the user, but that then gives me two memberships, one with the correct field values, one with initial "nil" values, and my manually created record.i.e. in my test

```
class User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :group_user_memberships
  has_many :schools, through: :memberships 


  #creates a  membership with nil values in some fields
   @user = create(user_type)

  #creates the correct, but secondary memberhsip
   member = @user.memberships.create(school_id: school.id, role_id: role.id)
```

What I don't want to do is have to create the user, find the membership id and then update the school_id in the membership as a) that is so many `SQL` operations and b) there would be no way of getting the correct record that was just created for that user.

Because my User has a relationship with Schools through Memberships, I was hoping to be able to find a way of passing the `school_id` to the User and that `nested_attributes` would insert the `school_id`

what I want, is to populate school and role when the User is created, and have these create the membership record. I *think* this is related to `before/after` hooks, but would love to know the best solution

Thanks in advance

EDIT

So, this is the code i use in my test, using Factory Girl. Maybe this is part of the question - I if I use rails console, I get this
    u = User.create(:firstname => "Dsd", :surname => "", :email => "aa@sdd.com")
    u.confirm!

I get a user SQL insert without a membership (or at least the log shows no membership INSERT)

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`active`, `confirma..... etc
```

In my test, using Factory Girl, I do get the membership. So maybe this is Factory Girl, but I can't see where in the Factory I get the membership. Here is my user Factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
sequence(:email){ |n| "user#{n}@example.com".downcase }
    firstname "MyString"
    surname "MyString"
    password "a1234567"
    active false

    factory :an_administrator do
      after(:create){|a| a.roles << create(:admin_role)}
    end
    factory :a_pupil do
       after(:create){|a| a.roles << create(:pupil_role)}
    end
  end
end
```

and my role factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :role do
    factory :admin_role do |f|
      name 'administrator' 
    end  
    factory :pupil_role do |f|
      name 'pupil'
    end
  end
end
```

So yes, I guess this is Factory Girl - creating a user_with_school_membership might be the answser perhaps?

Comment: Please, show the actual code that you have, not fake code. For example: @user = create(user_type) doesn't make any sense.

Comment: look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: `when I create a User, it creates a blank membership record which doesn't have the correct initial values` with what part of code? you didn't show it to us. if you somehow create an empty membership than you can pass there `school_id: school.id, role_id: role.id` directly during this action of user creation.

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated - I think you may have answered my issue - new EDIT above...